# How to sort columns in a HDB to apply the p attribute

Tags: kdb

I have a HDB that is date partitioned. I want to apply the p attribute historically to a specific column. As far as I am aware, to do this, I need to first ensure this column is sorted in a way that all common occurrences are adjacent. Currently, this is not the case. How can I sort this HDB so that this column in each partition has common values adjacent to each other.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xasc` on disk.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/asc/#xasc

You'd want to sort each partition and apply the parted attribute. Could build up the paths with `.Q.PD` & `.Q.PV` as I don't think this is something that exists in dbmaint.q.

- This is just a general idea, it is untested so use on some test data and modify to meet your hdb structure if needed.
- You may need to modify the xasc part if you want additional sorting within each part.

```
{[tbl;sortPartCol]
  {[sortPartCol;path] sortPartCol xasc path;@[path;sortPartCol;`p#] 
   }[sortPartCol] each distinct ` sv/: (.Q.PD cross `$string .Q.PV) cross tbl
   }
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qpv-partition-values
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qpd-partition-locations

Comment: Note that sorts in kdb are stable, so if this was in time order to begin with, it should still be within each group of symbols.  So aj / binary searches etc will work.

Comment: thanks, I thought that but wasn't 100% sure